# How to put multiple JSON objects from GET request into JSON Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I've got a get endpoint that gives me all the information about all the restaurants that are present in the database (I've pasted the response below).

Is it possible to actually store all those JSON Objects in an array, so that later I could iterate through all of them and put the information in the correct layout? If so, could you briefly describe how to do it? I've seen some answers here that point to JSONArray but as far as I'm concerned it worked when one attribute returns an array and not when GET request returns an array of objects. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
[
      {
        "Name": "Bar1",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Long 124",
        "City": "Warsaw",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 42
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bar2",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Sesame St. 124",
        "City": "Moscow",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 42
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bannered Mare",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Nice St. 654",
        "City": "Budapest",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 45
      },
      {
        "Name": "Rest",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Flickering St. 12",
        "City": "Madrid",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 50
      },
      {
        "Name": "Resting traveller",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Sesame St. 44",
        "City": "London",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 45
      },
      {
        "Name": "Frying Pan",
        "TypeName": "Bar",
        "Address": "Long St 124",
        "City": "Berlin",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 45
      },
      {
        "Name": "Burgers",
        "TypeName": "Fast food",
        "Address": "Broad St. 543",
        "City": "Cracow",
        "Opened": null,
        "NumberofSeats": 54
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate over a JSON array:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
....
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseJsonString);
for (int i = 0; i  < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Do whatever you want with jsonObject.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't used POST metod, GET is not good solution for sending data to Server. If your want to sent JSONObject in get request you must to add this json your URL.

Comment: I don't want to send this data, I want to receive it therefore GET is used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). With it you can parse your JSON array to a List object and can directly use it as you would like to.

At [futurestud.io](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) you can find a clear tutorial series about Retrofit. There you can find basically everything you will need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Volley` and `Gson` to parse `Json` into a List view or Recycler View.